# java nested class - eclipse issue

Tags: java, eclipse, nested

I require a nested class, however I have developed using the one class one file system. I have simply moved the class that needs to be nested, inside the outer class and left the instantiation of the inner class the same. However, when trying to debug in eclipse, my nested class gets the following error message `" Source not found." -(ClassNotFoundException)` . However the code works fine, its just that I cant actively debug and see the current line of exception in my nested class.

```
public class Tract {
    public class chicken{

    }
    public Tract{
        chicken = new chicken(d);
    }
}
```

thanks,
daniel

Comment: You might want to edit the `constructor` of `Tract` :). Have you tried to `clean` and `build` your project in Eclipse?

Comment: Not sure you can have a variable name having the same name as a class. Use Java convention: class = Chicken and variable = chicken.

Comment: This [SO Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525334/debug-in-eclipse-classnotfoundexception) might help