# class editor RXTXport.class not found?

Tags: java

In order to communicate with my serial port I downloaded rxtx for windows 64 bit and pluged into my eclipse. Everything looks fine. But while I'm debugging it when it comes to

```
SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) portIdentifier.open("ListPortClass", 300);             
int b = serialPort.getBaudRate();
```

it goes to class file editor and says rxtxport.class not found. What could be the issue?

Comment: do you step in a method call with `F5`? does the programm throw an Exception at that line?

Comment: yes but there is no any exception.

Comment: Did you add the RXTXcomm.jar inside the lib directory of your eclipse project?

Comment: I've neved had this issue with RXTXcomm on Eclipse or NetBeans, maybe this question may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525334/debug-in-eclipse-classnotfoundexception

Answer (score 0):

The problem sounds like a classpath problem. I'd say check the Eclipse Build Path.

Weirdly, the code snippet you provided did not contain said class, either it's incomplete or you might have the problem that it is a referenced class and a further 3rd party library is needed (ie, your package of rxtx is incomplete).

I'm not familiar with rxtx myself, so I cannot say if this is a definite probability, and on the other hand, this also comes down to the original answer: It is most likely a classpath problem, check whether all required libraries are included in the Eclipse Build Path.